# Send email in azure function under apps service plan

Tags: python, azure, email, azure-functions, smtplib

Im having azure function app with app service plan and I use python as programming lang. How can I send email from Azure functions... Is that possible  with app service plan or do I need to choose third party services like "twilio grid" or please suggest the possibilities....

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use twilio sendgrid as it [integrates very nicely with Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python) as an output binding using the [SendGrid extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid).

You can then create a function like

```py
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, sendGridMessage: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:

    value = "Sent from Azure Functions"

    message = {
        "personalizations": [ {
          "to": [{
            "email": "user@contoso.com"
            }]}],
        "subject": "Azure Functions email with SendGrid",
        "content": [{
            "type": "text/plain",
            "value": value }]}

    sendGridMessage.set(json.dumps(message))

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Sent")
```

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python) for more details and the [blogpost](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-emails-csharp-dotnet-with-azure-functions-and-sendgrid-bindings) on twilio. There is a [free plan](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/) to get started.

Using the Office 365 SMTP relay and Microsoft Graph API are also great options if you already have an Office 365 subscription. But it requires you to write the code yourself as there is no out-of-the box output binding.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to use `Twilio SendGrid` to send emails from azure functions. Alternatively, you can also switch to logic apps which provide many connectors including the one to send the mails

[image]

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Sending Email with Microsoft Azure](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure-2021#create-a-twilio-sendgrid-account)
2. [Office 365 Outlook - Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/)